# How to add a file name to byteArray in Java while storing to DB through JPA

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot

I have an inputstream which converting to byteArray to store to a Oracle table.
I'd like to add a file name before saving to table.

```
InputStream   inputStream = url.openStream();
byte[] errorByteArray = inputStream.readAllBytes();
Document doc = new Document("Error","application/zip",errorByteArray);
docRepo.save(doc);
```

I am getting a UUID kind file name when downloading the file from my another API to download this file. I like to give a meaningful name while storing. How can I do it?

Comment: Put it in another column in the table is the easiest way

Comment: unfortunately i cant control the table definition.

Comment: hacky... prefix the byte array with file name as bytes, use fixed length block and split it on read

Comment: From what package is ```Document``` ?

Comment: Document is my entity class

Comment: Not that this will necessarily help in a solution, but it should take ```InputStream``` as well in a ctor

Comment: `new Document("Error-" + title, ...);`?

Comment: But that require some changes from API and UI as well. am trying to avoid those changes.